# How to create symbolic link when I insert a X10 firecracker USB device

Tags: symbolic-link

I'm playing with a device called a X10 firecracker. It's a serial port device that lets me turn off/on things like lights in my home. I connect it using a Logitech *USB to serial port* dongle. When I connect the device to my Ubuntu 16.04 system, it creates a `/dev/ttyUSB0` file. However, to make it work with the little amount of software that's available for it, I need a symbolic link:

`/dev/firecracker --> /dev/ttyUSB0`

I can manually create it after each reboot by:

`sudo ln -s /dev/ttyUSB0 /dev/firecracker`

How can I make it so this symbolic link gets created automatically on firecracker insertion?

In pseudo-code:

When firecracker is inserted

wait for `/dev/ttyUSB0`

then create`/dev/firecracker`

Ideas? Thanks, Al

Comment: Did you try the old c290 variable:
export X10_PORTNAME=/dev/ttyUSB0

Comment: @ubfan1Thanks! Where do I put this command, my .bashrc? If ttyUSB0 doesn't exist yet, will it fail? Do I change X10_PORTNAME to **firecracker**, or **/dev/firecracker**, leave it alone, or something else? Cheers, Al

Comment: @troylatroy how do I do the highlighting myself?

Comment: @ubfan1 I put it into my .bash_aliases file, and I can now see the export with an echo command, but it didn't allow the software to open the serial port. I guess it really still wants /dev/firecracker. Thanks for trying. Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema using a couple of these guys ` around what you want to highlight.

Comment: Probably a udev rule, check /lib/udev/rules.d for examples.  Also check out Hightower's  amh-x10 (version 1.06 if you can find it), and Benedi's X10-automate for Linux native controls which might work with the firecracker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the easy way out... I added `ln -s /dev/ttyUSB0 /dev/firecracker` to `/etc/rc.local`.